# Can I install multiple copies of a Snap package?

Tags: snap

Is it possible to install or run multiple copies of a snap package, each with it's own isolated copy of app config / data?

Comment: I know it's possible to install two instances of the same snap package, because I've done it, but I don't remember how I did it. I'm posting this comment as a service to anyone who would otherwise post an answer claiming in it that it can't be done.

Comment: Parallel snap installs is listed as upcoming on [the snapd roadmap](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-snapd-roadmap/1973). If you have the `snapcraft.yaml` then you may be able to do it now by renaming the snap, snapping by [setting up LXD](https://snapdocs.labix.org/clean-build-using-lxc/4157) then running `SNAPCRAFT_CONTAINER_BUILDS=1 snapcraft` (not `snapcraft cleanbuild`), then installing the snap with `--dangerous`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do parallel installs from version 2.36 of snapd (`snap --version`), which includes the version on Ubuntu 18.10.

```
# Enable parallel instances
sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true

# First instance - normal install (not required)
sudo snap install myapp

# Second or more instances
sudo snap install myapp myapp_two
sudo snap install myapp myapp_three
```

Not that the instance name must match `<snap-name>_<instance-key>` - it can't have an arbitrary name.

Documentation: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/parallel-installs/7679