# how to run two different versions of a snap in parallel?

Tags: snap

Is it possible to run two versions of a program in parallel via snaps? By "running in parralel" I really want to have two windows open with e.g. different versions of blender. If this is possible, how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Must both versions be snap packages? Are you open to other packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install multiple copies of a Snap package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026075/can-i-install-multiple-copies-of-a-snap-package)

Comment: Yes, this solves my question. Thanks a lot!